# Kafka Consumer Custom MetricReporter not receiving metrics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, metrics, consumer, datadog

I've created a class that implements `org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric` like so:

```
public class DatadogMetricTracker implements MetricsReporter {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
        System.out.println(configs);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(List<KafkaMetric> metrics) {
        System.out.println(metrics);
    }

    @Override
    public void metricChange(KafkaMetric metric) {
        System.out.println(metric.metricName().name() + ": " + metric.value() + " tags: " + metric.metricName().tags());
    }

    @Override
    public void metricRemoval(KafkaMetric metric) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

}
```

Then I register the class as a metric reporter when I set-up the Kafka props:

`properties.put(ConsumerConfig.METRIC_REPORTER_CLASSES_CONFIG, "com.myco.utils.DatadogMetricTracker");`

When I start my consumer, `configure` gets called and `init`, then `metricChange` is called one time with a batch of metrics for which the values are all 0 or -Infinity, then it never gets called again. How do I get my metric recorder to fire again?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Nope. Ended up taking a different approach

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the code and metricChange method doesn't get called apart from initially registering the metric. So better to use some alternative approach. As of now, I will be implementing the periodic read of metrics and publishing of them since in our case Prometheus will scrape metrics from our application. One more important point is, since values are already calculated internally so, will be using only gauge to populate the values for prometheus

It works in case of JMX reporter because they create dynamic bean and when Mbean's attributes values are checked (Through JConsole or something) then actual method of getting metric's value is called so it works there, here is the code:

```
        public Object getAttribute(String name) throws AttributeNotFoundException, MBeanException, ReflectionException {
            if (this.metrics.containsKey(name))
                return this.metrics.get(name).metricValue();
            else
                throw new AttributeNotFoundException("Could not find attribute " + name);
        }
```